# Incorrect syntax near ',' (within the dates not working)

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax

I'm getting the above SQL error after executing this query.

```
SELECT r.SectionIDNum, r.PeopleIDNum, r.Completed, c.CourseID, s.DistrictIDNum, s.EndDate
FROM Registration r, Course c, Section s
WHERE r.SectionIDNum=s.SectionID AND c.CourseID=s.CourseIDNum AND r.Completed='Y'
AND s.EndDate between ('2012-06-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and ('2013-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Apparently, the commas in the dates are causing the error but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Usually `('2012-06-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` is used in the context of date conversion. So you are missing the function name here. E.g. for an Oracle DBMS the correct way should be `to_date('2012-06-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You should always tag SQL questions with the specific DBMS, since there are lots of differences between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CAST() Function (CAST converts value of one data type to a different type. In this case, CHAR to DATETIME):

```
SELECT  r.SectionIDNum 
        ,r.PeopleIDNum 
        ,r.Completed 
        ,c.CourseID 
        ,s.DistrictIDNum 
        ,s.EndDate
FROM    Registration r
       ,Course c
       ,Section s
WHERE  r.SectionIDNum=s.SectionID 
  AND  c.CourseID=s.CourseIDNum 
  AND  r.Completed='Y'
  AND  s.EndDate BETWEEN CAST('20120630' AS DATETIME)
       AND  CAST('20130701'AS DATETIME)
```

You could also use:

```
 CONVERT(DATETIME,'20130701')
```

Comment: The error now says `TO_DATE is not a recognized built-in function name.`  I suppose this is mend for Oracle DBMS?

Comment: @Esther I assumed that you were using Oracle based on your example. I have updated my answer for SQL SERVER

Comment: Thanks so much!  I used your updated code but now it says `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`  Can you please help?

Comment: @Esther Check to see if the SQL you ran matches my example, as I changed it several times.

Comment: `31-JUN-2012` is out of range, since June only had 30 days in 2012.

Comment: @Azzi: This time I actually copied and pasted your entire code to the SQL and ran it.  Same error came up.  I'm confused.

Comment: @Azzi Your example was using a non-default date format (DD-MMM-YYYY). I edited it to use YYYYMMDD, which is a more reliable format in SQL Server (someone has to approve the edit before it's shown, though).

Comment: @Azzi: Thanks for the help!  The code actually works.  Because I'm asking for 20130701, which has not occurred yet, the error says the date is out of range.  Hence, I changed it to 20130625 and it works. :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with dates in the future. The only problem is with dates that don't exist at all, like 31 in months that only have 30 days.

Comment: @Barmar: Good catch... I just figured out while changing dates in the query.  Guess I learn every day.  Thanks Barmar!

Comment: If your EndDate is a datetime, only records from midnight of July 1, 2013 would be included in the above query, to include everything from the full day you would want to CAST them as DATE, not DATETIME.

Answer (score 1):

June only has 30 days in it.  So SQL Server is confused by your request to cast June 31 as a date.

This works fine:

```
SELECT CAST('2012-06-30' AS DATE)
```

One way to avoid end of month issues is to use the `DATEADD()` function, for example, to get one year and one day prior to July 1, 2013 like in your example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,(DATEADD(year,-1,CAST('2013-07-01' AS DATE))))
```

Also, remember that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so you're getting June 30 and July 1 in your example, perhaps just subtracting the year is sufficient.

Comment: You're right about that.  And thanks for pointing out about the `BETWEEN` is inclusive, because I didn't know that.